# Selenium.setTimeout does not wait for specified time

Tags: java, selenium

We have to continuously monitor a URL to check for its availability. I have used selenium for simulation.  Pasted below is the piece of code.

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, mainUrl);
selenium.setTimeout("90000");
selenium.open(mainUrl);
```

However, `selenium.timeout` does not work even if the URL does not get opened up in 90000 milliseconds. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Latest supports ```this.driver.manage().setTimeouts({...})```

Answer (score 0):

According the [selenium javadoc](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.RemoteWebDriverOptions.RemoteTimeouts.html), the example looks like this:

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
selenium.open(mainUrl);
```

Answer (score -1):

try use Thread.sleep():

```
 final String sUrl = "http://www.google.ca/index.html";

// Instantiate the Internet Explorer browser.
WebDriver oWebDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

// Open the main google webpage.
oWebDriver.get(sUrl);


try
{
  Thread.sleep(5000);
}
catch(InterruptedException ex)
{
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

If you'd like to check for availability somtheing try also using fluentWait:

```
 public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
                }
);
                           return  foo;              }     ;
```

*An implementation of the Wait interface that may have its timeout and polling interval configured on the fly.
Each FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition. Furthermore, the user may configure the wait to ignore specific types of exceptions whilst waiting, such as NoSuchElementExceptions when searching for an element on the page.*

Hope this helps you)